# SqlDataSource InsertCommand and UpdateCommand throwing "illegal variable name/number""

Tags: vb.net, sqldatasource, updatecommand, selectcommand

I am trying to insert and update the table through SqlDataSource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ORAConnString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ORAConnString.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT DEPT_NAME,CATEGORY_NAME FROM SDIX_TCKT_CATEGORY"
    InsertCommand="Insert into SDIX_TCKT_CATEGORY (DEPT_NAME,CATEGORY_NAME,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DTTM)  values(:DEPTNAME,:CATEGORYNAME,'','')"  
    UpdateCommand="Update SDIX_TCKT_CATEGORY set CATEGORY_NAME=:CATEGORYNAME,MODIFIED_BY='',MODIFIED_DTTM=SYSDATE where(DEPT_NAME=:DEPTNAME) "                                       >
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="DEPTNAME" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CATEGORYNAME" />                                     
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="DEPTNAME" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CATEGORYNAME" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="MODIFIED_BY" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="MODIFIED_DTTM" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I need to insert null value for MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DTTM when insert new record?

I need to update userid(Need to get from code behind) and sysdate when updating the record in table?

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated...!

Comment: Your ':CATEGORY_NAME' parameter is spelt different in the statement and the parameter name array -> ':CATEGORYNAME'

Comment: I changed CATEGORY_NAME into CATEGORYNAME.

Comment: If you need to insert `NULL` then why are you actually inserting an empty string?

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong. If i use empty string ('')this will insert null into DB.

Comment: Is that possible to set the value from code behind for only certain parameter?

Answer (score 0):

`DBNull.value` instead of `''`

or simply do not specify null parameters.

**EDIT 1:** 
I tell you to use DBNull.value but i forgot that i use it by code

es. `YourSqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterName", DBNull.value)`

so in your sql update or insert probably you have to use the Sql `NULL`:

```
 Insert into SDIX_TCKT_CATEGORY (DEPT_NAME,CATEGORY_NAME,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DTTM) values(:DEPTNAME,:CATEGORYNAME,NULL,NULL)
```

Comment: No luck,Still i am getting same issue.

Comment: You can try with: <asp:Parameter Name="MODIFIED_BY"  ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"/>

Comment: And i tell you to use DBNull.value but i forgot that i use it by code es.  Sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterName", DBNull.value) so in your sql update or insert probably you have to use the Sql NULL: Insert into SDIX_TCKT_CATEGORY (DEPT_NAME,CATEGORY_NAME,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DTTM)  values(:DEPTNAME,:CATEGORYNAME,NULL,NULL)